# When you apply the chain rule to an inverse trigonometric function, why does the denominator change?

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

In step two below

[image: Khan academy exercise]

I'd say the derivative of $-6x$ is $-6$, and so I'd multiple the $-6$ with the numerator to get $-6$.

But I don't understand where $36$ comes from.

(I understand that $-6$ times $-6$ is $36$, of course, but why it's happened, I don't know, because multiplying a fraction by a scalar should only change the numerator, in my mind)

I assume that I'm missing a step, but I can't think what step. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: The denominator didn't change: $1+(-6x)^2 = 1+36x^2$.

Comment: Oh, it was stupid mistake with an exponential. Thanks!